# Filename in the fopen statement

Tags: c

The program will ask for the filename of the file you want to open. Then the contents will be displayed on the screen. This is what I got so far and i know it wrong. The one I stored in the variable filename should be the filename in the fopen statement.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[20];
    char c;

    clrscr();

    printf("ENTER FILE NAME: ");
    scanf("%s",&filename);

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fgetc(fp=fopen("filename","r"));

        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%c",&c);
            printf("%c",c);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    getch();
}
```

Is there any methods/functions that the one I stored in the variable filename will be in the fopen statement? I know there's something lacking in this program. I would gladly appreciate if you could help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrapped filename in quotes, so it looks for a file named `filename` and not whatever is in your filename variable. Try:

```
fp=fopen(filename,"r");
fgetc(fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, this statement is wrong:

```
scanf("%s",&filename);
```

What you are doing is passing a `char **` (technically, a `char (*)[20]`) to `scanf`, but instead you want just a `char *`, so you can get rid of the `&`, like so:

```
scanf("%s", filename);
```

Also note, that `scanf` has no way of knowing how big `filename` is (in this case, just 20 characaters), so if you type in too large of a file name, your program will crash (or worse). Also, if there are any spaces in the file name, you'll only get the first part of the file name. Instead, you can use `fgets` like so:

```
fgets(filename, 20, stdin);
```

Just be warned that this will also read a newline into `filename`, so you need to use `strlen` to remove it.

Second, the expression `fopen("filename","r")` is using the string `"filename"` as the file name. Just get rid of the quotes to use the variable.

Also, you call `feof(fp)` in your outer `while` loop without actually initializing `fp`. Don't do that. Instead, you should have `fp = fopen(...)` be in a separate `if` statement to make sure it opened properly:

```
if (fp = fopen(...))
{
    // TODO: read file here
}
else
{
    // file could not be opened properly!
}
```

Finally, you never assign the return value of `fgetc` to your local variable `c` (which, by the way, needs to be an `int` to distinguish `EOF` from other characters).

Comment: You should stated that there is a need to remove the trailing newline if you want to use the fgets.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[20];
    int c;

    clrscr();

    printf("ENTER FILE NAME: ");
    scanf("%19s", filename);//You cannot use spaces in the file name.
    if(fp=fopen(filename,"r")){
        while(EOF!=(c=fgetc(fp))){
            printf("%c", c);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```